# FATAL exited too quickly

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn, vps

I made an edit to my app.py file on my local machine, uploaded it through sftp while it was still running (really dumb but I wasn't even thinking) and now I can't restart supervisorctl because I get ERROR (abnormal termination)...

Is there any fix to this?

Comment: I understand how frustrating that can be. What does your supervisor configuration for your app look like?

Comment: Hi- this is the code I put into the supervisor config:[program:flask_project]
command = gunicorn app:app -b localhost:8000
directory = /home/www/flask_project
user = newuser

Comment: Do you have any more information that you've found out? any log files that could be helpful?

Comment: Hi again- thanks for your help. I checked the log files and I got flask_app (exit status 3; not expected)... I'm not 100% sure what happened as it was working perfectly before I updated the flask app.

Comment: I checked the other log and it says "worker failed to boot"